Enterprise Backup suitable for mass rollout
Our company wants to switch from Personal Backup to a different backup software. We have evaluated bvckup2, which is a great software that I recommended for all my family members, but it does not suit our needs.
Here are the requirements (until we find new ones ):

works on Windows 10 and Windows 11, 64 bit (client)
works on Windows (server-part, if any)
is a backup on a file basis (not a complete disk image backup)
keeps a history based on time (e.g. last 6 months are available)
keeps a history based on changes (e.g. last 10 backups are available, no real-time synchronization needed)
lets users access single files easily for recovery
can be deployed using Microsoft Software Center
offers a MSI installation (bvckup2 does not fulfil this criteria)
can be rolled out with a "template" of a backup with the settings recommended by our IT (bvckup2 partially fulfils this requirement)
has a comprehensive and complete documentation (bvckup2 uses a forum, which is hard to navigate and cluttered with user feedback)
offers support by email or phone
is fairly simple to use / hides advanced options by default (Personal Backup fails in this regard while bvckup2 is good)
handles large files efficiently (bvckup2 does a great job there)
continues in case of failures (e.g. if a single file is not accessible)
auto-retries in case the server is not available (e.g. VPN connection is reestablished)
auto-retries in case the local hard disk is not available (e.g. back up as soon as the external storage is reattached)
smart recovery in case of auto-retries, i.e. does not restart the whole backup, but continues where it left off
costs ~2000 € for 65 users (first time)
costs ~1500 € for 65 users (update/support contract)

The software may/can:

be gratis
be open source (FOSS)
be client-based (client pushes backups onto server)
or server-based (server pulls backups from client)
if client-based, works with network shares (backup folder will be a SMB mounted drive)

Non-requirements:

anything with cloud. We want a local (server-based) backup in our company.
Encryption of the backup, the admin should be able to restore files without need of a user password
Compression of the backup, the user should be able to restore files without the need of manually decompressing them. The tool may use compression during transfer or even store files in a compressed way.
Deduplication in the backup. The tool may do that, but we have large enough disks.

Environment information, if needed:

65 users
estimated 20 GB of backup per user (latest snaphot)
plus all the archive space (history)
several people with really large files (up to 4 GB)
typically 1 Gib/s network speed, unless in HomeOffice, where speed may drop to 10 Mib/s

What we found so far:

Kopia seems to create the backup locally, then encrypt it and then sends it to the server. We don't want a single large file and we don't need encryption.
BURP needs a Linux server
Duplicati can be configured to either keep a number of copies or delete after some time, but I need both: I want at least the last 10 backups (even if that is more than 6 months) and at least 6 months (even if that is more than 10 backups). CPU usage during backup is quite high (>50%; i7; encryption enabled).


A Kopia repository is made up of several smaller files organized in (quite a lot) folders (Backup of 139,4 GB (single files up to 12 GB) results in 43.3 GB (there are some large logs which have good compression) in 3565 files and 56000 folders (I don't get that) most files in the order of 25 MB, I used default settings). But I'm only a single user, so no idea about administration. I don't quite understand why compression is not a requirement when the transfer rate may drop to 10 MBit/s. Last 10 changes - so it should have a file system watcher which detects changes and saves them immediately?

@Arsenal: thanks for the details. I clarified the non-requirements (most of them are actually "may" requirements) as well as last 10 changes (is "last 10 backups", no real-timy synchronization)
